# gpg/pinentry - Can't enter passphrase outside terminal

Tags: gpg, pinentry

I am trying to decrypt a gpg file inside a script. When I run `gpg -d file.gpg` in the terminal, I get prompted to enter the password in a curses dialog box. But when I run a script containing that line, I get "gpg: decryption failed: No secret key", or a silent failure if not run from an interactive terminal.

Ideally, if gpg is trying to run from a non-interactive shell (I think that's the word for what I mean but I'm not sure - basically if it's run from a script), when I'm running X, then I would like it to open a terminal window running `pinentry-curses`.

If I set my pinentry program to run with qt or gtk, then a graphical window pops up every time, no matter where it comes from. That's the kind of behaviour I'd like to replicate - I just don't want it to depend on qt or gtk.

Answer (score 1):

I can get you some way towards a solution, assuming gpg2, and with the caveat that I make no claims to security etc.

Pre-create a terminal reserved for typing passwords. In it give the two commands:

```bsh
tty
gpg-agent --pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses --daemon sleep 999999
```

This will print the pty being used, say, `/dev/pts/10`, and then run the gpg agent, which will "hang" in the `sleep` so that no further reads are being done in this terminal.

When you need to decrypt something in some other shell, first set its environment with:

```
export GPG_TTY=/dev/pts/10 
export GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
```

where 1000 is your user id.
(You can get the name of this socket by starting `gpg-agent` with option `-v`. I'm sure there is some cleaner way of getting it.)

Note the `:0:1` added at the end of the info; it should really be the pid of the agent and the protocol version, but 0 seems to be accepted. (If the socket is not at the above pathname, you might not be using `gpg2`, or you may have some options set in your config files).

You **must now also** add option  `--use-agent` to the `gpg` decrypt command.
It should cause the curses version of the pinentry program to appear in the pre-created terminal, where you can now enter the password.